# java synchronised positives/negatives and usage

Tags: java, synchronized

I've read all the theory I can on how synchronised methods operate, but I need a practical example.

What is the positive and negative or using synchronised like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean sync = Boolean.valueOf(args[0]);
        Person person1 = person2 = new Person();

        person1.write(sync, args[1]);
        person1.read(sync);
        person2.write(sync, args[1]);
        person2.read(sync);

    }
}
```

write is naming the project: (either synchronized or not)

```
public static String project_name = "";
```

and read is printing the current name for the person (either synchronized or not)

So what is the difference when write and read are regular methods versus synchronised methods?

What could go wrong if I use the regular method?

Comment: For starters, you'd need to have multiple threads to see any difference.

Comment: What if 100 persons tried this

Comment: You mean if you had 100 `Person` variables? Wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: What do u mean multiple threads, as in multiple people attempting to rename the static field right? so if 100 people tried doing this together you would need sync right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "people". 100 humans operating 1 keyboard?

Comment: Yea each person is controlled by a human, so if 100 humans tried to rename the field at the same time, operating on their own pcs (each person different keyboard)

Comment: How? Is this a server application? More context please.

Comment: Think of a multiplayer game, and all the online players are attempting to edit a static field. It could be 100 players see an item appear on the ground and all spam click it, or 100 players are renaming the name of a group that they are all in.

Comment: If they're running on separate PCs, they're not seeing the same field.

Comment: They are. They're all playing on the same server, they can interact with each other. Like club pengiun, runescape, tanks, they can all interact and edit static items (i.e the map they're placed in by interacting with it)

Comment: Are you telling me this is a server application? How do the clients connect to it?

Comment: The clients connect to a port and ip, though i dont really see the relevance. If you don't understand just assume that the players are 'looking at the same field'

Comment: If there are multiple threads accessing the same field, you probably need synchronization.

Comment: Back to the original question then, what could go wrong

Comment: A million things. Your question is way too broad.

Comment: Start by checking [Oracle Lesson - Concurreny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:** 
A non-synchronous method being accessed by multiple sources will generally cause undefined behaviour, but a synchronised method will work every time.

**Longer answer:**
I don't think you fully understand what a synchronised method is, because your code does not demonstrate it at all.

If there really is a possibility of 100 people accessing the same method then you will have undefined behaviour when the same variable is being written to and read from.

However, if that method is accessed synchronously then each method call will be added to a queue and will happen in order.

For example:
100 different threads(People?) could call `SynchronizedProjectName.renameProject("exampleName");` and/or `SynchronizedProjectName.projectName();` on the code below, and no error would occur, and no read/write would happen at the same time.

```
public class SynchronizedProjectName {
    private string project_name = "";

    public synchronized void renameProject(String newProjectName) {
        project_name = newProjectName;
    }

    public synchronized string projectName() {
        return project_name;
    } 
}
```

You should always always use some sort of thread safe strategy when dealing with multiple threads/users, and if you don't, then you should expect your code to misbehave and probably crash.

See here for a little bit of extra info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Note: It will pay the read the whole Synchronization tutorial provided by Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: That's assuming only one instance of the class will be used to call the synchroniezd method (OP variable is `static`). A `synchronized` method is like a `synchronized(this)` block.

Comment: @AxelH correct. That appears to be what OP wants (from comments above).